How much of the world’s landscape or continents could be visibly changed by a natural/unatural disaster that humans could still potentially survive?
Considering the resilience of humanity, I’m curious about the extent to which a disaster could visibly alter the Earth’s landscape or continents while still leaving a chance for human survival. What type of natural or unnatural disaster could drastically reshape the Earth—enough to be seen from space—yet still allow some humans to endure the aftermath? How would such a disaster impact the planet, and what would survival look like in this drastically changed world?

Over what time span? If you're only interested in the immediate aftermath then the ISS has humans and you could go much further than Nepen Nep has suggested and destroy the planet wholesale, if you're talking about eventual repopulation then we have a different level of survival at play. Also I have to VTC, one question at a time.

"drastically reshape the Earth—enough to be seen from space" this is an extremely low bar. There is a lot visible from space. You can just turn off the electricity in a city and that would be visible from space (at night, there would be a black spot where the city is).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There are many different kinds of disasters that could happen. If you allow a "slow disaster," then the flooding of Florida over the next 100 years will qualify.

All of it, because some humans live in space.
My suggestion is you have a massive asteroid a bit smaller than the moon slam into the earth. The surface is in general resurfaced, but a small number of humans survive in space, with the mega rich fleeing it. After x hundred years when it cools down, humans seed the earth with new life and then return down to the surface.

such an impact would make orbiting around Earth extremely hazardous (to put it mildly)

You can keep orbiting the earth as long as you stay within around a million kilometers. That's far enough to avoid any damage.

Don't forget about all the radiation damage that humans living in space receive. Our atmosphere protects us from many cosmic rays that would damage genes up there. Humans also have effects from not living with gravity.

It won't be a good time for them, certainly, and there would be technological issues in ensuring survival and protecting themselves from radiation with water shields say.
